# Styled checkbox with icons made of primitives doesn't completely render on trigger, works fine in Blend

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I've a locked/unlocked padlock icon implemented as a checkbox with some drawing primitives that are changed by a trigger on IsChecked. It works fine in Blend. In VS2010, and in the built application, the padlock body disappears when the padlock switches from the default open to the closed state, so only the closed "hoop" is visible. The hoop is in the correct place- it does move so the control does seem to switch canvases. The body reappears again when switching back. Has anyone encountered similar/knows what could be happening?

The template;

```
<Canvas x:Key="PadlockClosed" Width="21" Height="21">
    <Path Data="M10.668887,13.83234 C10.168442,2.3320701 20.347726,0.31172793 21.014875,13.894838" Height="9.451" Canvas.Left="2.719" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="0.162" Width="10.362" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="#FFE2E2E2"/>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{DynamicResource PadlockBody}"/>
</Canvas>

<Canvas x:Key="PadlockOpen" Width="21" Height="21">
    <Path Data="M10.668887,13.83234 C10.168442,2.3320701 20.347726,0.31172793 21.014875,13.894838" Height="9.451" Canvas.Left="11.102" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="0.162" Width="10.362" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="#FFE2E2E2"/>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{DynamicResource PadlockBody}"/>
</Canvas>

    <Canvas x:Key="PadlockBody">
        <Rectangle Height="12.8" Canvas.Left="0.125" Canvas.Top="8.0" Width="15.082" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4" RenderTransformOrigin="0.704,0.5">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                            <SkewTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="-90" CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8B8989" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Path Data="M15.1,16.333333 L15.1,19.750334" Height="5.417" Canvas.Left="6.375" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" Canvas.Top="11.333" Width="2.167"/>
        <Ellipse Height="2.5" Canvas.Left="6.125" Canvas.Top="11.333" Width="2.584" Fill="#FF0A0101"/>
    </Canvas>
```

What I'm using to test;

```
<CheckBox Template="{DynamicResource PadlockCheckBox}" Width="20" Height="20" IsChecked="True"/>
```

Only reason resources are dynamic is for simplicity with Blend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody else seems to have a better answer, so although it's a bit lame I'll post the workaround I discovered. Instead of re-using PadlockBody in both PadlockOpen and PadlockClosed canvases, I copied it to create PadlockBody2, and used that in one of the cases. For some odd reason, using the same canvas resource in both cases within the same control template appears to foul things up in the built application, even though it works fine in Blend.